# Chromium and webmidi: Platform dependent initialization failed

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, opera, midi

After I changed the OS ([Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) to [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)), webmidi support acted weirdly in Chromium and Opera. It seems it can’t be enabled any more: the page https://webmidi.info/ tells *Access to WebMIDI is denied* without any tooltip to ask permission.

I tried to enable *Insecure origins treated as secure* in chrome://flags, but it didn’t change the problem.

Also, depending on the application I test, I can get the error *WebMidi could not be enabled. DOMException: Platform dependent initialization failed.* in the console.

With my previous system, webmidi was supported and enabled smoothly in Chrome, Chromium and [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29).

Comment: WebMIDI used to work on Ubuntu till Chrome version 94. Since Chrome 95 I noted the same error message as you did. I have reported  the issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1254727&q=&can=4